# Python dynamically pass argument to string format function

Tags: python

How I can dynamically pass arguments to format function of string, Below is sample, Here my "text" string would be dynamic and it may have n number of dynamic argument, Function will receive a tuple, I want to fit the tuple value in the dynamic locations. But the format function is not working with tuple.

```
text = "Good {0}, {1} !!!"
def sayHello(*args):
    return "Good {0}, {1} !!!".format(args)
print sayHello('Morning', "Tom")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another asterisk when using `format`

```
text = "Good {0}, {1} !!!"
def sayHello(*args):
    return "Good {0}, {1} !!!".format(*args)
print (sayHello('Morning', "Tom"))
#Good Morning, Tom !!!
```